# Duplicate entities in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I'm trying to extend *Products in carts* report grid. I needed to separate products for each customer and add a *Customer name* column. So for example a product with `id` number equal to `123` may exist in two different carts which means for two individual customers. So I need two rows for product `id=123`.

But at the moment when this happens I get a familiar message:

```
Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Quote) with the same id "123" already exist
```

I tried to rewrite my query starting from `sales_flat_quote_item` as main table (to have unique entities) but since I'm extending `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection` this fails with this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.entity_id' 
in 'field list', query was: SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)
FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `main_table` ...
```

Currently my `prepareForProductsInCarts` function starts with:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/quote_item_collection');
```

and ends with:

```
// reset methods may be redundant
$this->getSelect()
    ->useStraightJoin(true)
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::DISTINCT)
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$this->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS, $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS));
$this->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM, $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM));
$this->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP, $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP));
$this->getSelect()->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE, $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE));
```

What can I do to allow or work around duplicated entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was extending `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection`:

```
class Name_Sapce_Model_Resource_Reports_Quote_Collection
    extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection {
```

and after going through base codes I found the only thing I need to change to set my own resource model is invoking `_init()` from `_construct` method this way:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::_construct();
    $this->_init('sales/quote_item');
}
```

An escape to call `parent::_construct();` may be necessary and that's the reason why I used parent's parent class directly.

Now `main_table` correctly is an alias for `sales_flat_quote_item`.